# How can I ignore data that is not of numerical value in a column when finding the max numerical value in the column?

Tags: c#, datatable, dbnull

I have a column in a datatable that normally consist of numerical values but there are rare occasions where letters will be present in the column. This is due to customize equipment taking measurements and when a measurement is out of range of its limits a word or abbreviation is recorded. 
With that being said I am having a problem getting the max numerical value from the column because one or more rows might contain letters.

I get the error message "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types "!!

```
  Decimal maxDataValue = Convert.ToDecimal(mainDataTable.Compute("max([Data])", string.Empty));
  Decimal roundMaxData = Math.Round(maxDataValue);
```

is it a way to work around rows who contain letters and find the max numerical value in the column?

Comment: What data type is the column?  If it's numeric (double or decimal) then it can't contain letters: are these getting converted to DBNulls?  Or is it a string column, in which case using max isn't going to work well?  My guess from the error is ALL your rows contain letters, or maybe even the DataTable is empty, because your compute statement will usually work correctly in other cases.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing is saying that there are also null values in your data too. The other problem of having string data in the column you are trying to sum makes it difficult to use `Compute` directly. You could convert the DataTable to an Enumerable though and operate on it using Linq. Something like this could work...which returns `6.25` as the result.

```
var data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(string));
data.Rows.Add("1");
data.Rows.Add("2.0");
data.Rows.Add("3.25 kg");
data.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value);

var sum = data.AsEnumerable()
.Where(d => d["Data"] != DBNull.Value)
.Sum(d =>
{
    var columnData = d["Data"].ToString();
    var numericalString = new string(columnData.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.').ToArray());
    var numericalValue = decimal.Parse(numericalString);

    return numericalValue;
});
```